# Remove multiple rows with specific string values

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a data frame with a few hundred columns. I would like to remove the rows for selected columns with the values "Item skipped" or "".

See below for example. Ideally I would like to remove all rows in which the columns 'animal' and 'Insurance' contain "Item skipped" or "", but do not want this to apply to other columns.

In my actual data frame there are about 34 columns where I want to remove the columns with these strings and 128 where I do not. Advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
dat <- data.frame(animal=c("dog","cat","Item skipped", ""), Insurance=c("Y", "N","Item skipped",""), condition = c("",
                  "Asthma","Item skipped",""), age = rep(c(6,10), each = 2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter_at` with selected columns or range of columns

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  filter_at(vars(animal,Insurance), all_vars(!. %in% c("Item skipped", "")))

#  animal Insurance condition age
#1    dog         Y             6
#2    cat         N    Asthma   6
```

---

Or with base R you could use `rowSums`

```
cols <- c('animal', 'Insurance')
dat[rowSums(dat[cols] == "Item skipped" | dat[cols] == "") == 0, ]
```

Comment: thanks. what if i wanted to use dplyr but wanted to list the columns by name because they are not consecutive ie  dat %>%
  filter_at(vars(animal,Insurance), any_vars(!. %in% c("Item skipped", "")))

Comment: @monkeyshines I initially did a mistake, you might require `all_vars` instead of `any_vars`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In base R without a `for` loop:

```
dat[!rownames(dat) %in% which(dat$animal %in% c("Item skipped", "") | dat$Insurance %in% c("Item skipped", "")), ]`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this with a for loop, especially since your dataset is smallish.

```
> remove_cols <- c('animal', 'Insurance') # vector of names of all columns you'll use to drop rows
> remove_vals <- c('', 'Item skipped') # values which indicate a row that should be dropped
> 
> for(col in remove_cols){
+   dat <- dat[!dat[[col]] %in% remove_vals, ]
+ }
> 
> head(dat)
  animal Insurance condition age
1    dog         Y             6
2    cat         N    Asthma   6
```

Answer (score -1):

Using R base without need of applying more packages:

```
# Find rows that match content of 2 column cell values.
rows_to_delete <- which(dat$animal == "Item skipped" & dat$Insurance == "Item skipped")

# Delete row. 
# Add result in new dataframe [dat2].
# Keep old dataframe for comparison [dat].
dat2 <- dat[-rows_to_delete, ]
```